# how is below code working? aren't tuples supposed to be immutable? please clarify

Tags: python

```
>>> tuple1 = (1,2,3,4)
>>> tuple2 = (3,4,5,6)
>>> tuple1 = tuple1+tuple2
>>> print tuple1
(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>>
```

Sorry if this is a noob question, and posting this as I could not find anything related to this.

Comment: The original tuples are never mutated. You created a new tuple.

Comment: The contents of a tuple are immutable, but nothing stops you from reassigning the variable.

Comment: The same applies to integers: `sum = 10`, then `sum = sum + 5` never mutates the integers. It only assigns a **different integer object**.

Comment: note that `tuple1 += tuple2` also creates a new reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, nowhere did you alter the *contents* of the tuples. **Names** on the other hand are mutable. You changed what the name `tuple1` points to.

You could have done this:

```
tuple1 = (1,2,3,4)
tuple2 = (3,4,5,6)
new_tuple = tuple1 + tuple2
```

leaving the name `tuple1` untouched, and the tuple it references also remains untouched. The new tuple you created then is assigned to a different name.

What you **can't** do is assign directly to the indices of a tuple:

```
>>> tuple1[0] = 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Compare this to a `list` object, where the above assignment would have worked.

The operation `tuple1 + tuple2` creates a **new** tuple object, with the contents of the other two tuples. The result can be assigned, including the names `tuple1` or `tuple2`.

I strongly recommend you read up on how Python names work, and how they are separate from things like tuples and integers (which are objects). See [Ned Batchelder's *Facts and myths about Python names and values*](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).